# Configured openvpn client on Fedora with .ovpn file but still can't reach the website that requires it

Tags: networking, fedora, openvpn

My company uses OpenVPN to access some services online and provided me a *.ovpn* file. I use Fedora and i was following [this tutorial](https://hide.me/en/vpnsetup/fedora/openvpn/) but it seems it didn't configured it perfectly. Indeed when following the steps

```
bash-5.1$ sudo sh -c 'echo \"mylogin\" >> /etc/openvpn/credentials'
bash-5.1$ sudo sh -c 'echo \"MyPassword\" >> /etc/openvpn/credentials'
bash-5.1$ cat /etc/openvpn/credentials 
"mylogin"
"MyPassword"
bash-5.1$ sed -i 's/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass \/etc\/openvpn\/credentials/g' /home/ac/Documents/configfile\@mycorporation.com.ovpn
nohup openvpn --config /home/ac/Documents/configfile\@mycorporation.com.ovpn & 
[1] 54409
bash-5.1$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

But when trying to go to the website that requires the vpn I still can't get it.
So how can I configure my openvpn client on Fedora when receiving a .ovpn file?